# Print out JSON data in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm using cockpit-project API to get physical status about the environment Server printed out. Here's what I have as my React code:

```
"use strict";

const output = document.getElementById("output");
const jsonData = [output];

class CockpitTest extends React.Component {
  getOutput(data) {
    output.append(document.createTextNode(data));
  }

  async componentDidMount() {
    await cockpit.spawn(["/usr/local/bin/statusdemo"]).stream(this.getOutput);

    console.log(output);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <ul>
        {jsonData.map((data, i) => (
          <li key={i}>{data.text}</li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<CockpitTest />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

what I'm trying to do here is to get that data printed out in my component and write if statements for my program to act differently on different JSON response.

btw here's how my console prints out `output`:

```
<pre id=​"output">​"{
    "psu1": {
        "status": "ok",
        "volt": "233"
    },
    "psu2": {
        "status": "ok",
        "volt": "233"
    },
    "mgmt1": {
        "link_status": "no link",
        "bps": 0
    },
    "mgmt2": {
        "link_status": "1000Mbit",
        "bps": 12984
    },
    "data1": {
        "link_status": "100000Mbit",
        "bps": 1003567
    },
    "data2": {
        "link_status": "100000Mbit",
        "bps": 4055645
    }
}

"</pre>​
```

I get to see the JSON data in my console window but not my component, it is just blank. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const output = document.getElementById("output");
```

This line assign **output** with value is NodeElement, not the string in that html tag.

If you want to get the content of **output** element, try to get the innerHTML

```
const output = document.getElementById("output").innerHTML
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: now I get this error "Uncaught TypeError: output.append is not a function
    at Function.getOutput (<anonymous>:26:14)"

Comment: @Karl this error is caused by getOutput() function. I can only help you with the output string. Try console.log the output. If the string is printed succesfully, you need to do the rest work of rendering yourself...